# Why NLA animations are limited to 6 when exporting to FBX?

Tags: animation, export, file-format, nla-editor

I'm getting this problem when trying to export from blender to any other program in Fbx format using NLA stacks for animation, when exported it only seems to save 6 out of 12 animations

[image]
Don't know if it helps to find the problem, but 4 out of 6 of those unexportable animations were clones at first and later modified.

FBX export settings used.

[image]

Comment: Hi! Please don't add solved to the question title, instead accept your answer. How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found out what was wrong if anyone else got the same problems, all exporting NLA strips are controlled in Nonlinear animation tab:

[image]

Found it in the documentation: 
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/nla/strips.html